# "Invalid Date format. It must be YYYY-MM-DD" -- Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to redefine Django's Restframework default Date input type from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY, while any post request is sent from frontend.

I tried with postman to test the scenarios but Django is only accepting it with YYYY-MM-DD format

I followed the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date_input_formats) tried to set settings.py with with configs like

1.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],
    }
```

2. 

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": [("%d-%m-%Y")],
    }
```

models.py

```
class MasterIndividualMembers(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

views.py

```
def create_individual_member(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        birth_date = request.POST.get('birth_date')

        try:
            individual_member = MasterIndividualMembers(
                firstname = firstname,
                lastname = lastname,
                birth_date = birth_date,
            )
            individual_member.save()
```

But nothing seems to work. Please someone help, its like Iam stuck here.

Comment: The first example *should* work, as-is

Comment: But unfortunately didnt worked as expected.

Comment: Try to set `USE_L10N = False` and also set Django's DATE_INPUT_FORMATS. Maybe that will help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS

Comment: Hard luck again, nothing happened. Something wrong with my app, by any chance? All other POST,GET requests are called successfully, just this one for date input is facing problems.

Comment: Also ```USE_L10N = False``` worked when saving the data from django admin page. But restframwork is not using this somehow.

Comment: Can you share where the error comes from? Is it from the serializer?

Comment: Hi @BrianDestura, I am handling the input from views.py file. I added the piece of code in my post.

Comment: Since you are using the date directly in the model, rest framework settings will not apply. In this case you need `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`. Can you also share what value you have used in `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` and `USE_L10N`? If possible try to also share `MasterIndividualMembers` model

Comment: Updated the models.py in the question. ```DATE_INPUT_FORMATS``` was already there, which I tried with two formats, currently it is the 1st one and ```USE_L10N = False```